# How to make rsync --fake-super store owner and group as string in the extended attributes?

Tags: permissions, backup, rsync

I am running a server on Ubuntu server 18.04. I want to write scripts to easily backup and restore my programs and data individually to/from a different system. Say I have an application with its program files in **/var/www/myapp/** and its config files in **/etc/myapp/** which are owned by **myapp:myapp**.

*All code below is run from a script with sudo.*

I run the backup using:

```
rsync -aR -M--fake-super \
    /var/www/myapp       \
    /etc/myapp           \
    backupuser@backuphost:myapp/root/
```

When restoring my app I run:

```
adduser --system --group --no-create-home myapp
rsync -a --fake-super -M--super backupuser@backuphost:myapp/root/ /
```

As expected, **/var/www/myapp/** and **/etc/myapp/** are restored, but not the ownership. It turns out that `rsync`, even when running with --fake-super doesn't store owner and group as strings in the extended attibutes, but tries to map them to existing users/groups. So already on my **backuphost**, where I don't want to create the user and group **myapp**, owner and group are assigned the first free numeric ids (in this case 113:118):

```
xattr -l myapp/root/var/www/myapp/anyfile
> user.rsync.%stat: 100664 0,0 113:118
```

Is there a way to make `rsync` store owner and group as string in the extended attributes, so they will be easily restored on the new system? So running `xattr -l myapp/root/var/www/myapp/anyfile` on **backuphost** would result in something like `> user.rsync.%stat: 100664 0,0 myapp:myapp`?

Comment: perhaps `--numeric-ids` on save and restore has some effect?

Comment: @meuh Thank you for your suggestion! Unfortunately that doesn't work. I need something like the inversion of ```--numeric-ids```, something that enforces string owner and group names.

Comment: As an alternative, you might look at `duplicity` and its gui `deja-dup` which uses `librsync` and will do incremental backups to a remote on which you are a simple user. (The only problem you might have is it does not preserve hard links).

Comment: @meuh That worked for me. You're a lifesaver!